# ¿Por qué en Python no se pueden declarar variables que empiezen con un número?

Tags: python

¿Por qué en Python no se pueden declarar variables que empiezen con un número?

Ejemplo:

```
prueba1 = "hola mundo" #bien
1prueba = "hola mundo" #mal
```

Comment: Revisando la documentación oficial, no explica la razón, solo dice que no se puede. Puedes revisarlo [aquí](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#identifiers).

Comment: Lo más natural sería preguntarse, ¿Por qué declarar un identificador que empiece por número?

Comment: @NaCl A veces uno quisiera hacerlo. Por ejemplo  `2pi = 6.2831853071...`

Comment: @leonbloy Para eso existe lo que mencionas en Perl, igual en C# se pueden utilizar nombre de palabras reservadas con el prefijo `@` antes del identificador, es más bien cuestión de reglas, en lo que mencionas, ¿Por qué no llamarlo `_2pi = ...`, o `TwoPi`? Personalmente es más cuestión de gustos.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Casi ningún lenguaje de programación [*] admite identificadores (nombres de variables) que comiencen con dígitos numéricos.

Como explican [aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/a/342192/277304), aceptar tales identificadores introduciría ambigüedades en la sintaxis.

Por ejemplo, no quedaría claro si en

`x = 1600L`

nos referimos a una variable con nombre `1600L`, o un literal numérico con el sufijo `L` (long). Peor aún, si aceptamos identificadores formados sólo por dígitos sería imposible distinguirlos de literales numéricos.

```
x = y + 20  # qué tal si hay una variable llamada "20" ?
```

Claro que uno podría introducir restricciones, del tipo "aceptamos identificadores que empiecen con dígitos si contienen al menos una letra y si no pueden confundirse con un literal numérico... " pero esto sería muy feo y frágil. Lo más sencillo y elegante es convenir en prohibirlos de entrada.

---

[*] La única excepción que conozco es Perl - porque en este lenguaje las variables se distinguen con un prefijo ("sigil") como `$` . Así, no hay peligro de ambigüedad.

[**] La restricción está presente incluso en identificadores de elementos en HTML4 ([atributo `id`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-are-valid-values-for-the-id-attribute-in-html)), aunque en este caso es más difícil justificarla. De hecho, en HTML5 se levantó la restricción.

Answer (score 7):

Lo que comentas no es exclusivo de Python, en casi todos los lenguajes no se permite declarar una variable que empiece con un dígito. Y tiene una explicación lógica: es para evitar que se cree un nombre de variable que sea igual que un número.

Si se permite que una variable comience por un dígito, podría darse el caso de que haya una variable cuyo nombre esté formado sólo por dígitos. ¿Cómo lo diferenciarías entonces del entero que se escribe igual? Por ejemplo (notación C):

```
int a = 12;
int 1 = 2;
int b = a + 1;
```

Ese último `1` (el de `int b = a + 1;`), ¿se refiere al número 1 o la variable `1`? ¿Cuál sería entonces el valor de `b`: 13 ó 14?

E incluso si el nombre de la variable no fuera sólo dígitos, hay casos en los que podría coincidir con un número dependiendo de los diferentes formatos que permita el lenguaje. Por ejemplo, los hexadecimales: 0x60 es igual a 96 en decimal.

Answer (score 1):

Tal y cómo comenta nuestro compañero [Alvaro Montoro](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/34864/4499) en su respuesta, esto no es algo exclusivo de Python, sino que prácticamente ningún lenguaje de programación admite el uso de números al principio de un identificador.

¿Por qué es esto? Pues, veamoslo desde el punto de vista analítico:

Imaginemos que declaramos la siguiente variable, en Python :

```
1 = 13
```

Esto provocaría un error de sintaxis en todo el lenguaje y pediría volver al inicio, imagina el mismo ejemplo en C:

```
int 1 = 1;
```

Es otro que va a explotar en el momento que se compile.

Mirandolo entonces desde el punto de vista lógico, es donde se obtienen las respuestas.

Hagamos de nuevo la pregunta, ¿Por qué no se puede? Ahora sí, la respuesta es simple:

Los lenguajes de programación normalmente cumplen 3 etapas (las más resumidas):

```
Análisis Léxico > Análisis Semántico > Construcción del Ejecutable
```

Es en el Análisis Léxico donde todas las palabras y simbolos escritos en tu archivo de código fuente se convierten en unidades entendibles para el compilador, tomemos de nuevo la entrada en python:

```
1 = 13
```

Al ser analizado por el tokenizador, obtendríamos los siguientes resultados:

```
<Número, 1>
<Símbolo, '='>
<Número, 13>
```

Y es justo en la entrada del proceso de análisis semántico donde dice que tu entrada no cumple ninguna regla definida en el lenguaje *[(Leer: Backus-Naur Form)](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notaci%C3%B3n_de_Backus-Naur)*.

Dicho todo esto, la mejor forma de entender un identificador es la siguiente *(Por lo menos para mí)*:

Un identificador puede empezar por guión bajo o por letra, luego del primer caracter, puede contener letras, números o guiones bajos.

Traducido:

```
<identificador> := <letra> o '_' [ <letra> | <número> | '_' ]*
```

Aunque la regla definida anteriormente no es necesariamente aplicada a todos los lenguajes de programación.

Answer (score 1):

Puede llamarlo **convenio**: *cualquier literal que empiece por un número se trata como número*. Siguiendo este convenio evitas caer en la ambigüedad en los siguientes casos:

- `1e10` número con exponente
- `1j` número imaginario
- `0x10` número en hexadecimal
- `0o10` número en octal
- `0b10` número en binario
- `20L` entero *long* (python2)